# Save current state of entire GUI in Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have an app written in Qt that has many widgets, including lists, tables, trees, line edits, etc.  As the user progresses through the app, they may need to save the current state, leave, and come back later to pick up where they left off.  I do not have a the data separate from the GUI (all data is stored in the widgets themselves).  I have found a way to loop through all the widgets and save the current state, but it takes a significant amount of time.  Is there a faster or built in way to save the current state of the GUI?  I am trying to avoid re-writing the code to have a data model that is only represented by the GUI due to limited time available.

Answer (score 0):

Is [Qt's session management](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/session.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't think the session management helps in this regard, as it only tells you when to save your state, but doesn't do the saving and restoring for you, whereas the OP wanted a method for automatically saving the whole state (which is IMHO not possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can save every param on its actual change, or when user leaves the page, not on exit. And *don't try* to save every parameter of every widget, use smarter algorithm

Answer (score 0):

As a good crossplatform and flexible way to save state of your GUI is to use Qt's mechanism -- `QSettings` ([official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QSettings.html#details)).

But, really, there are re-writing moments, which you can't avoid.